# maven error "The POM for ... is missing" - right after maven downloads the pom

Tags: maven, netbeans, pom.xml, maven-nbm

So maven downloads the pom then declares that it is missing. Then it proceeds to download the jars.

Heres the log

```
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for     http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/
Downloading: http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org/netbeans/api/org-openide-text/RELEASE71/org-openide-text-RELEASE71.pom
Downloaded: http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/org/netbeans/api/org-openide-text/RELEASE71/org-openide-text-RELEASE71.pom (2 KB at 3.5 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Reading resolution tracking file /home/homeu1/.m2/repository/org/netbeans/api/org-openide-text/RELEASE71/org-openide-text-RELEASE71.pom.lastUpdated
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /home/homeu1/.m2/repository/org/netbeans/api/org-openide-text/RELEASE71/org-openide-text-RELEASE71.pom.lastUpdated
[WARNING] The POM for org-openide-text:org-netbeans-api:jar:RELEASE71 is missing, no dependency information available
```

...
then the end error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jalopy2-netbeans: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.notzippy:jalopy2-netbeans:nbm:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org-openide-text:org-netbeans-api:jar:RELEASE71 in http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of netbeans has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project jalopy2-netbeans: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.notzippy:jalopy2-netbeans:nbm:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org-openide-text:org-netbeans-api:jar:RELEASE71 in http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of netbeans has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I dont get it, if I look  into mavens repository the pom and jar are downloaded, the sha1 is fine. Every other dependency seems to resolve fine and if I try to remove that dependency I get.

```
Project uses classes from transitive module org.netbeans.api:org-openide-text:jar:RELEASE71 which will not be accessible at runtime.
```

Ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you have `org-netbeans-api-RELEASE71.jar` in your local repository?

Comment: I would assume one of your dependency is wrong (may be version?) check that. Just delete the given artifact ([ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jalopy2-netbeans: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.notzippy:jalopy2-netbeans:nbm:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org-openide-text:org-netbeans-api:jar:RELEASE71 in http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ )...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had artifactId and groupId swapped. D'oh